# How to extract cascades of layers from a directed graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, code-request

I request an efficient `Code` for the following computations. The computations do exactly what I intend to achieve (I assume?), however, the code looks poor and inefficient, and I cannot go on with higher order layers  because of my poor programming skills. Therefore, for illustrative purposes, I could compute two layers only.

Here is a brief description of how to identify `cascades of layers of one-edge neighbors` of a given sector i in a directed graph.

1. Layer(i,1) denotes layer 1 of sector i, which is defined by one-edge neighbors of i (denoted by N(i)={sectors(i), binary links(i)});
2. Suppose that sectors j, k, l are elements of the set `sectors(i)` in `N(i)`, for each sector j, k, l, find their one-edge neighbors: N(j), N(k), N(l);
3. Subtract binary links(i) from the `Union` of binary links(j), binary links(k), binary links(l). The remaining list of binary links and the associated sectors define Layer(i, 2);
4. To obtain Layer(i,3), repeat the same procedure using N(j), N(k), N(l);
5. Identification of layers should stop when all the sectors in the given `start` network are exhausted.

Here is the code implementing the above procedure for two layers only:

```
el = {"EGW" \[DirectedEdge] "MA2", "EGW" \[DirectedEdge] "HLT",   "EGW" \[DirectedEdge] "AGF", "EGW" \[DirectedEdge] "WHS", "EGW" \[DirectedEdge] "TSC", "EGW" \[DirectedEdge] "CST", "HLT" \[DirectedEdge] "MA2", "HLT" \[DirectedEdge] "EGW", "HLT" \[DirectedEdge] "TSC", "HLT" \[DirectedEdge] "CST", "AGF" \[DirectedEdge] "EGW", "AGF" \[DirectedEdge] "HLT", "AGF" \[DirectedEdge] "WHS", "AGF" \[DirectedEdge] "TSC", "CO12" \[DirectedEdge] "HLT", "CO12" \[DirectedEdge] "AGF", "CO12" \[DirectedEdge] "WHS", "FIN" \[DirectedEdge] "AGF", "WHS" \[DirectedEdge] "CO12", "TSC" \[DirectedEdge] "CO12", "TSC" \[DirectedEdge] "FIN", "CST" \[DirectedEdge] "FIN"};

vl = {"MA2", "EGW", "HLT", "AGF", "CO12", "FIN", "WHS", "TSC", "CST"};

ewl = {0.021, 0.019, 0.017, 0.026, 0.023, 0.026, 0.015, 0.011, 0.015, 
 0.013, 0.017, 0.015, 0.026, 0.016, 0.025, 0.018, 0.018, 0.017, 
 0.016, 0.012, 0.021, 0.014};

wGraph = Thread[{el, ewl}];

gr = Graph[el, VertexLabels -> "Name", PlotLabel -> "Given a graph", 
 ImageSize -> 250];
HighlightGraph[gr, Subgraph[gr,layer1 = NeighborhoodGraph[gr, "MA2", PlotLabel -> "Layer 1"]], ImageSize -> 250];
el1 = EdgeList[layer1];
vl1 = VertexList[layer1];

HighlightGraph[gr,Subgraph[gr, layer21 = NeighborhoodGraph[gr, "EGW"]]];
HighlightGraph[gr,Subgraph[gr, layer22 = NeighborhoodGraph[gr, "HLT"]]];
el21 = EdgeList[layer21];
vl21 = VertexList[layer21];
el22 = EdgeList[layer22];
vl22 = VertexList[layer22];

el21Uel22 = Union[el21, el22];
layer2 = Graph[Complement[el21Uel22, el1], VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 PlotLabel -> "Layer 2", ImageSize -> 250];

Row[{gr, Spacer[20], layer1, Spacer[20], layer2}]
```

Here is what it produces:

[image]

I would be grateful if the efficient `Code` derives `layers`

- as a sequence of `Subgraphs` like I did above to allow for the reconstruction of the `starting` graph by sequentially clipping individual layers (`Subgraphs`) to each other.
- show the final layered graph as a `CommunityGraph`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Getting the layers

```
ClearAll[nextLayer, layersList]
nextLayer[g_] := Complement[
  EdgeList @ Apply[GraphUnion] @ Map[NeighborhoodGraph[g, #] &] @ VertexList[#], 
  EdgeList @ #] &;

layersList[g_, startingVertex_, steps_] := 
 Rest @ NestList[nextLayer[g], Graph[{startingVertex}, {}], steps]
```

***Examples:***

```
Transpose[{Range[5], layersList[gr, "MA2", 5]}] // Grid
```

[image]

```
MapIndexed[
   Graph[#, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> 200, 
     PlotLabel -> Row[{"Layer " , #2[[1]]}]] &] @ 
  layersList[gr, "MA2", 5] // Row[#, Spacer[10]] &
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `NestWhileList` to get a cycle-free list:

```
ClearAll[allLayers]
allLayers[g_, startingVertex_] := 
 Rest @ NestWhileList[nextLayer[g], Graph[{startingVertex}, {}], 
   DuplicateFreeQ @* List, All, Infinity, -1]
```

***Examples:***

```
MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &]@allLayers[gr, "MA2"] // Grid
```

[image]

```
MapIndexed[
   Graph[#, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> 300, 
     PlotLabel -> Row[{"Layer " , #2[[1]]}]] &] @ allLayers[gr, "MA2"] //
  Row[#, Spacer[10]] &
```

[image]

### 2. CommunityGraphPlot

Map `VertexList` on `allLayers[gr, "MA2"]` to get a community structure:

```
communitystructure = VertexList /@ allLayers[gr, "MA2"]
```

> ```
> {{"EGW", "HLT", "MA2"},
>  {"AGF", "EGW", "HLT", "TSC", "WHS", "CO12", "CST"},
>  {"CO12", "WHS", "CST", "FIN", "EGW", "HLT", "MA2", "AGF",  "TSC"}}
> ```

Use `communitystructure` in the second argument of `CommunityGraphPlot`:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[EdgeList@gr, communitystructure, 
 ImageSize -> Large, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 VertexSize -> Large, 
 CommunityRegionStyle -> (Opacity[.3, #] & /@ {Red, Green, Blue}), 
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[
   Opacity[.3, #] & /@ {Red, Green, Blue},
  {"Layer 1", "Layer 2", "Layer 3"},
  LegendMarkerSize -> Medium, "Spacings" -> {1, 1}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this very efficient code. It seems that the `code` is doing a slightly different computation than I was expecting. (1) The layers need to be mutually exclusive (in edges but not in vertices), (2) previously computed layers should not show up in latter layers. These conditions are violated in the code. I tried the code with different examples, but again these two conditions are not satisfied. One reason is that somewhere in the code, previously found edges are not subtracted from the latter layers.